# UI testing accessing specific screen directly : iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing a `UI` test for my app but the problem is when user signup in  app, takes a phone number and send verification code to that number and on the next screen I have to type in the verification code send to my number. The `UI` test fails because of this so is there any way I can bypass the verification code screen and jump directly to the next screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable in `app.launchEnvironment` like this:

```
        app.launchEnvironment["SKIP_VERIFICATION"] = true
```

In main target, before going to next screen you can check if `SKIP_VERIFICATION` is set,  skip this screen and move to next screen.

In main target you can get this variable like this:

```
ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["SKIP_VERIFICATION"]
```

Comment: There are some functionalities in which I want to reset the app state but how do I reset the app state in specific functions like if I want to reset the app state only when I want to test walkthrough screen but when the user is logged in once I don't want to reset the app state again so is there any way I can do this without writing launch arguments in set up function